# Information and guide for debugging errors when nodejs displays a function is not a function?

Tags: node.js, function, debugging

I am beginer and I can not determined reason of this error
How can I debug and know detail about it?

> Uncaught Exception : TypeError: common.initExpress is not a function

When I using console.log then it has been identified as a function

```
console.log(common)
```

Then results is:

```
[Module: null prototype] {
  default: {
    initExpress: [Function: initExpress],
    findIPAddress: [Function: findIPAddress]
}}
```

---

**Error code:**

```
    const logger = createLoggerInstance(import.meta.url);
    import * as common from '../common.js';
    const initWebsocket = async (port) => {
    logger.info('init WebSocket module standalone');
    console.log(common);
    const app = common.initExpress(express, port); // Error here
    common.add404ViewRouter(app);
   }
```

**code in file common.js:**

```
import createLoggerInstance from './logger.js';
const logger = createLoggerInstance(import.meta.url);

const initExpress = (express, port) => {
    // Can't even access the console.log line below
    console.log('inside initExpress');
    const app = express();
    //...
    return app;
};


const add404ViewRouter = (app) => {
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        logger.client('404 not found');
        res.status(404);
        
        res.send('404');
    });

    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        logger.error(err.stack);
        res.status(500);
        res.send('505');
    });
};

export default{
    
    initExpress,
   
    add404ViewRouter
  }
```